# In a master detail relationship how to get a list of master entities without detail entities crm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, entity-relationship

I'm using CRM 2011 and I have a 1-n relationship between EntityA(master) and EntityB(detail).
I need to get the list of EntityA records that are not related to any EntityB records. How can I accomplish this inside a plugin using query expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work (See the EDIT, it doesn't work):

```cs
var qe = new QueryExpression("entitya");
var entityBLink = qe.AddLink("entityb", "entityaid", "entityaid", JoinOperator.LeftOuter);
entityBLink.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("entitybid", ConditionOperator.Null);
```

It should create a SQL Statement that looks something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
FROM entitya
LEFT OUTER JOIN entityb on entitya.entityaid = entityb.entityaid
    AND ( entityb.entitybid IS NULL )
```

### EDIT - Working version

```cs
var qe = new QueryExpression("entitya");
var entityBLink = qe.AddLink("entityb", "entityaid", "entityaid", JoinOperator.LeftOuter);
entityBLink.Columns.AddColumn("entitybid");
var entities = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe).Entities.
    Where(e => !e.Attributes.Keys.Any(k => k.EndsWith(".entitybid"))).
    Select(e => e.ToEntity<entitya>());
```

The SQL statement for the first query does get generated as is, but since the null check is on the join and it is a left join, all EnityA entities get returned.

The bad news is in CRM there is no way to perform a sub query, or specify in the where clause, a linked entity's properties.  I really hope Microsoft spends some time with the next major release adding this type of functionality.

You can however perform the filter on the client side, which is what the C# code is doing above.

Comment: Already tried that and it hasn't the same behavior as the SQL statement. It always retrieves the EntityA records even if they are not related to any EntityB records.